# GitHub Actions の実行時間はJOB単位の実行時間ですか？

Tags: github-actions

GitHubActionsは、例えばProプランであれば無料枠が3000分が付与されますが、この3000分という時間はJOB実行時間の合計でしょうか？
例えば、１つのワークフロー内で複数並列JOBが走った場合は、ワークフローのスタートから終了までの時間ではなく、JOB１つずつに対して費やした時間がカウントされるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

請求に関することですので、最終的にはご自身で確認してください。

[GitHub Actionsの支払いについて](https://docs.github.com/ja/billing/managing-billing-for-github-actions/about-billing-for-github-actions)で説明されています。

- パブリックリポジトリは無料です。
- セルフホストランナーも無料です。
- Proにおける3000分／月はプライベートリポジトリに対するものです。
- Windowsは2倍、macOSは10倍の倍率が設定されています。例えばすべてmacOSで実行した場合、300分／月までとなります。

OSによって倍率が異なることから、Job単位での利用時間計算と思われます。